# Команды: вверх, вниз,влево,вправо

Tags: html

У нас есть команда center и похожие команды влево вправо, ну а как же сделать вверх, вниз. Подскажите пожалуйста, кстати здесь <vspace></vspace> не проходит:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы про теги отвечающие за форматирование -то наверное атрибут valign вам нужен

Comment: Но лучше CSS'ом сделать, атрибут `valign` _deprecated_

Comment: да лучше все на CSS делать) Но человек спрасил - я ответил